# Node js : Using Handlebars and Bodyparser together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In this basic program I would like to get user input using 'body parser' and then enter that input via handlebars onto the index page. I have attempted many times but can't seem to acheive it. Also does handlebars and bodyparser go together or should I be using something different.

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Bodyparser and Handlebars</h1>
        </header>
    <form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="text" name="name1">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
                  {{test}}
    </body>   
</html>
```

Node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require("path"); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', handlebars({
  defaultLayout: 'base',
  extname: '.html'
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //public directory

app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
    test: req.body.name1});
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.name1);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: bodyParser helps you collect form values that were submitted to the server.  You can then use that to construct a data structure that you pass to handlebar's `.render()` when rendering a template.  The two items handlebars and bodyParser have nothing to do with one another directly.  You just use one to collect data that you can then pass to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your post to `/` should be:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
    test: req.body.name1});
});
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Body-parser and handlebars work perfect togheter. Body-parser allows you to collect the request data inside the router controller and handlebars is a template engine that render the variables and more stuff.

You need to pass the text that you want to display to the POST router controller.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  name1: <input type="text" name="name1"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Put that form in other view or anywhere you want

Inside the controller pass the request parameter to handlebars:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
  test: req.body.name1});
});
```